# Customization greenlight for Bigbluebutton

Tags: bigbluebutton

i try ton install Customized greenlight,

i have install Bigblue button on aws ec2 and after that try to install costomized greenlight
i have cloned from github ......

```
i run this command as root:    cat ./greenlight.nginx | sudo tee /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/greenlight.nginx
```

then it gives the following :

tee: /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/greenlight.nginx: No such file or directory
Routes requests to Greenlight based on the '/b' prefix.

Only needed if using presentations and deployed at a relative root (ex "/b")
If deploying at "/", delete the section below

4. Configure Nginx to Route To Greenlight because the folder etc/bigbluebutton/nginx is missing